# Deceleration of spherical particle in fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, particle-physics

If I know the initial velocity of a particle entering a fluid, how can I calculate its deceleration over time ? What parameters would I need to know ? Viscosity of the fluid, weight of the particle ...?
I'm doing a basic model where particles move straight in a grid world, knowing the dimension of each box I would ideally like to have a coefficient b where v = v/b each time I change box (making the assumption that the velocity is constant in a box).
My particles are surronded by the fluid and traveling in it, I'm not talking about deceleration when entering the fluid really.

Comment: Assuming the particle is a sphere large enough to create turbulence, you'd also need to know the fluid dynamics of flow past a sphere.  See this: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/earth-atmospheric-and-planetary-sciences/12-090-introduction-to-fluid-motions-sediment-transport-and-current-generated-sedimentary-structures-fall-2006/course-textbook/ch3.pdf

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of fluid mechanics! The simple answer is, that there is no simple answer. Do you need the correct answer? Then you will have to study the nasty properties of the Navier-Stokes equation. Can you live with an approximation? Pick a simple linear or quadratic friction law and count your blessings that you don't have to study fluid mechanics!

Comment: For the first model I'm building, I'll just use an approximation. I've read things about Navier Stokes equation but it's way out of my league for this project. I'm just looking for something that's not obviously wrong... And I'm talking about nanoparticles, so I hope it's not big enough to create a turbulence...

Comment: See @Ernie's good resource as well as [Stokes' law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law) to calculate the drag force of viscous fluids on small spherical particles.